# Retrofit2 call to wikipedia API not getting desired response

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, wikipedia-api

so, if I type this call into the browser

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:Monet 1871 Seascape.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url`

i get the following reponse

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"query": {
    "normalized": [
        {
            "from": "Image:Monet 1871 Seascape.jpg",
            "to": "File:Monet 1871 Seascape.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "pages": {
        "-1": {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Monet 1871 Seascape.jpg",
            "missing": "",
            "known": "",
            "imagerepository": "shared",
            "imageinfo": [
                {
                    "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Monet_1871_Seascape.jpg",
                    "descriptionurl": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Monet_1871_Seascape.jpg",
                    "descriptionshorturl": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=30782803"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So I set up the following retrofit call

```
Retrofit retrofit =new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
SearchInterface request = retrofit.create(SearchInterface.class);
    Call<WikiObject> call =request.getImageUrl(
            "query",
            "json",
            "imageinfo",
            "Image:Monet 1871 Seascape.jpg",
            "url"
    );
```

and my interface

```
@GET("api.php?")
Call<WikiObject> getImageUrl(
        @NonNull @Query("action") String action,
        @NonNull @Query("format") String format,
        @NonNull @Query("prop") String prop,
        @NonNull @Query("titles") String titles,
        @NonNull @Query("iiprop") String iiprop

);
```

and the response is

```
"batchcomplete":"",
"query":{
   "normalized":[
        {
           "from":"Image:Monet 1871 Seascape.jpg",
           "to":"File:Monet 1871 Seascape.jpg"
        }
   ],
   "pages":
       {
       }
 }
```

My pages are null.  I am only trying to get the url if the imageinfo.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
@Faruk Toptas suggested I intercept my call and my call is correct.  If I enter my call into a browser, I get the expected response.  So I have some other problem.  Any suggestion?

**UPDATE 2**
I'm getting this
`Unable to resolve Lretrofit2/Response; annotation class 7336'\`

Comment: Use okhttp logger interceptor. You can see requests and responses from logcat. You will find out whats wrong. https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: Thanks, see update.

Comment: How does the `WikiObject` type look like?

Comment: I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org to create Objects.  I seem to be having trouble at the -1 inside the pages object.  `jsonschema` converted this to a _1.  Doesn't seem to be working